# How to find out current transaction timeout in Java EE 6?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Is there a way to find out the current transaction timeout (or even better the remainting time until timeout) of the current UserTransaction in Java EE 6?

I can inject **UserTransaction** in any CDI managed bean but the API has no such options.

If it isn't possible in plain Java EE, is there a way in JBoss 7.x/EAP 6.x?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

It's posible change it globaly only in JBoss console for all session beans.
But I would not change default timeout. Basically everything can be splited into smaller transactions.

Using @TransactionTimeout in EAP 6 is not working always.